# Html inside VBScript to display array results and restart the function

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

This is my code. I have to connect to a 324k+ row spreadsheet and return values in a table on an html page. The function works correctly and it returns values. I am stuck having it just update the current table without reloading the page and then the "search again" button doesnt work to start the function again. It must be in HTML webpage type interface. But i have the choice between Javascript and VBScript. I have taken some naming out due to security.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CS Number Search Tool</title>
        <table id="Header" border="1" bgcolor="E6E7F5">
            <thead bgcolor="69BDF5">
                <tr>
                    <th width="1130"><font color="F2F2F2" />the title i created</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <table id="Incidents" border="1" summary="CS Search Results">
            <thead bgcolor="DAF0F5">
                <tr >
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
<button onclick="vbscript:ReadExcel()">Search</button>
</head>


<body>
<script Language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">

  Option Explicit

  Dim idTimer

  function ReadExcel()

  Dim myXlsFile
  myXlsFile = "path\\reprogrammingticketsPOX.xlsb"
  Dim mySheet
  mySheet = "Sheet1"
  Dim my1stCell
  my1stCell = "A1"
  Dim myLastCell
  myLastCell = "F324375"
  Dim blnHeader
  blnHeader = True



  Dim srcphr, Message
  Dim Title

  Message = "Please Enter A Number To Search"
  Title = "CS Search Tool TycoIS"

  srcphr = InputBox(Message, Title)
  If srcphr = "" Then
  Exit Function
  End If

  Dim arrData( ), i, j
  Dim objExcel, objRS
  Dim strHeader, strRange

  Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
  Const adOpenKeyset      = 1
  Const adOpenDynamic     = 2
  Const adOpenStatic      = 3

  ' Define header parameter string for Excel object
  If blnHeader Then
  strHeader = "HDR=YES;"
  Else
  strHeader = "HDR=NO;"
  End If
  ' Open the object for the Excel file
  Set objExcel = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
  ' With IMEX=1 numbers won't be ignored; tip by Thomas Willig.
  ' Connection string updated by Marcel Niënkemper to open Excel 2007 (.xslx) files.
  objExcel.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
  & myXlsFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Format=xlsb;" _
                & strHeader & """"

    ' Open a recordset object for the sheet and range
    Set objRS = CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )
    strRange = mySheet & "$" & my1stCell & ":" & myLastCell
    objRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & strRange & "] WHERE [CS_No]= '" & srcphr & "' OR [Cust_No]='" & srcphr & "' OR [Job_No]='" & srcphr & "' OR [New_CS_No]='" & srcphr & "' " , objExcel, adOpenStatic

    ' Read the data from the Excel sheet
    i = 0
    Do Until objRS.EOF
        ' Stop reading when an empty row is encountered in the Excel sheet
        If IsNull( objRS.Fields(0).Value ) Or Trim( objRS.Fields(0).Value ) = "" Then Exit Do
        ' Add a new row to the output array
        ReDim Preserve arrData( objRS.Fields.Count - 1, i )
        ' Copy the Excel sheet's row values to the array "row"
        ' IsNull test credits: Adriaan Westra
        For j = 0 To objRS.Fields.Count - 1
            If IsNull( objRS.Fields(j).Value ) Then
                arrData( j, i ) = ""
            Else
                arrData( j, i ) = Trim( objRS.Fields(j).Value )
            End If
        Next
        ' Move to the next row
        objRS.MoveNext
        ' Increment the array "row" number
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ' Close the file and release the objects
    objRS.Close
    objExcel.Close
    Set objRS    = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

    ' Return the results
    ReadExcel = arrData

Call writeTable(arrData)

End function


sub writeTable(arrData)

Dim intCount, objSheet
For intCount = 0 To UBound( arrData, 2 )

document.write "<!DOCTYPE html>"
document.write "<html>"
document.write "<head>"
document.write "<title>CS Number Search Tool</title>"
document.write "<table id='Header' border='1' bgcolor='E6E7F5'>"
document.write "<thead bgcolor='69BDF5'>"
document.write "<tr>"
document.write "<th width='1130'><font color='F2F2F2' />Tyco Integrated Security - Panel Reprogramming Project CS Search</th>"
document.write "</tr>"
document.write "</thead>"
document.write "</table>"
document.write "<table id='Incidents' border='1'>"
document.write "<tbody bgcolor='DAF0F5'>"
document.write "<tr>"
document.write "<th width='200px'>Old CS Number <BR>"& arrData( 0, intCount ) &"</th>"
document.write "<th width='150px'>Site Number <BR>"& arrData( 1, intCount ) &"</th>"
document.write "<th width='150px'>Customer Number <BR>"& arrData( 2, intCount ) &"</th>"
document.write "<th width='150px'>Job Number <BR>"& arrData( 3, intCount ) &"</th>"
document.write "<th width='150px'>New CS Number <BR>"& arrData( 4, intCount ) &"</th>"
document.write "<th width='300px'>Source Sheet <BR>"& arrData( 5, intCount ) &"</th>"
document.write "</tr>"
document.write "</tbody>"
document.write "</table>"
document.write "</head>"
document.write "</html>"

Next

Call searchExcel()

End sub

Sub searchExcel()
    document.write "<button onclick=ReadExcel()>Search Again</button>"
End Sub
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it correctly, you say, the `Search Again` button won't work. That is because the function call attached to the onclick event is not between double quotes. Change

```
Sub searchExcel()
    document.write "<button onclick=ReadExcel()>Search Again</button>"
End Sub
```

to

```
Sub searchExcel()
    document.write "<button onclick=""VBScript:ReadExcel()"">Search Again</button>"
End Sub
```

And this part will perform better.

The next challenge you'll encounter is that the table after a Search Again action is written after the first table. You can make that more clean by creating a table with an ID, get the table with `document.getElementById` and set the `innerHtml` property with the new data.

Comment: I have gotten it to work up to the point of everything working but still that button doesnt want to work no matter what i try. I will try to post the updated code soon so it can be looked at.